# Cannot create file '*.mdf' because it already exists

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, code-first

I am using **Entity-Framework** in a **Winforms** application. The application connects to **MSSQLServer** and everything works fine. Then I detach the database and copy the `.mdf` file to the app folder and change the connection string to use the local `.mdf` file, still everything works fine.

The problem is that when I copy my application together with the database to another PC suddenly EF tries to recreate the database and throws this error:

> Cannot create file **'Path\MyDatabaseName.mdf'** because it already exists.
>   Change the file path or the file name, and retry the operation. CREATE
>   DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check
>   related errors.

Context Initializer is set to `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`:

```
Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyContext, DAL.Migrations.Configuration>("MyConnectionString"));
```

Also, automatic migration is off and database is created by EF Code-First on Sql-server and is already updated to the latest migration so no migration is needed.

Connection string for the first scenario is:

```
<add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="Server=DESKTOP-XXXXXXX; Database=MyDatabase; Integrated Security=True; Connect Timeout=30;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient">
```

and for local `.mdf` file is:

```
<add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MyDatabase.mdf; Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

So, What is going on here??

Comment: What are the connection strings for the 3 scenarios?

Comment: @Neil I updated the question

Comment: Do both machines have the same version of SQL server? (SQLExpress or whatever).  It would be a good idea to specifiy the full path to the MDF, rather than `|DataDirectory|`.

Comment: The development machine has SQLServer 2016 but on the target machine I installed SQLLocalDB

Comment: @Neil Do you think that this is happening because versions are different?

Comment: I think a path problem is more likely.  Have you tried specifying a full path in the connection string?

Comment: @Neil No I haven't tried full path. But if I delete the database, EF creates an empty database in the `|DataDirectory|` folder. So we can be sure that the path is correct. Basically this is the confusing part: EF ignores the existence of the database file and tries to overwrite it with a new file.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, go to **C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\SQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA** folder and delete the same database name **'*.mdf'** file if exist. After deleting it and recreate the database, the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 5):

### For SQL Server running in docker:

Since I am using an SQL server in docker I have to get inside the docker using `docker exec -it <CONTAINER ID> bash` and delete `mdf` file from the`/var/opt/mssql/data` directory.

Steps:

1. `docker ps` -> Copy `CONTAINER ID` of the docker container running SQL Server
2. `docker exec -it <CONTAINER ID> bash` -> Now you can view/modify a file inside the docker
3. `cd /`
4. `cd /var/opt/mssql/data` -> To go to the directory of `mdf/ldf` file
5. `rm -rf <database_name>.mdf` -> To delete `mdf` file
6. `rm -rf <database_name>_log.ldf` -> To delete `ldf` file

This resolves my issue.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is to do the following:

1. Open up your command prompt
2. Open services (type in services.msc)
3. Find your SQL Server Service instance -> right click ->  then click STOP
4. Navigate to the path specified (ex.Path\MyDatabaseName.mdf) and delete it or create a backup if you need to access it later
   *(You will likely have to do the same with the log file as well)*
5. Retry your attempted operation